# R - Functions argument into aggregate function

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm pretty new to R, so please bear with me. I have created a function and am passing arguments into it. In the function I'm attempting to use the aggregate function and pass the original parameters.

```
GetPlotFactors <- function(df, par1, par2) {
  index.value = match(par1,names(df))
  names(df)[index.value]
  headers = c(par1, 'A', 'B')
  sub <- subset(df, df[index.value] == par2, select = c(par1, 'A', 'B') )
  df.test <- aggregate(B~par1+A, FUN = 'sum', data = sub)

  Error in model.frame.default(formula = B ~ par1 + A, data = sub) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'par1')
```

There seems to be a problem with the aggregate function, I`m not sure what is causing the error.

dput(head(sub)):

```
structure(list(Policy = structure(c(7L, 7L, 17L, 7L, 17L, 17L
 ), .Label = c("A", "B","C", "D", "E","F", "G", "H","I", "J", "K", 
"L", "M", "N","O", "P","R"), class = "factor"), A = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Rank_1", "Rank_2", "Rank_3", 
"Rank_4", "Rank_5", "Rank_6", "Rank_7", "Rank_8", "Rank_9", "Rank_10", 
"Rank_11", "Rank_12", "Rank_13", "Rank_14", "Rank_15", "Rank_16", 
"Rank_17", "Rank_18", "Rank_19", "Rank_20", "Rank_21", "Rank_22"),
, class = "factor"), 
B = c(0, 274.325, -809569.5495, -9534.5307, 15529.3678, 
-151893.0683)), .Names = c("Policy", "A", "B"), row.names = c(80L, 
100L, 145L, 172L, 201L, 203L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: There seem to be a few problems here (where is the closing `}`?). But let's start with a reproducible example. Could you copy `dput(head(df))` to your question so that we can see what `df` looks like?

Comment: Hi Hugh, this was only a part of the code. So I forgot to add the closing bracket. I will add the dput to the comment.

Comment: What is `GetPlotFactors` supposed to do? I understand the function isn't completely defined, but I'm trying to get a sense of the logic of your code.

Comment: `aggregate(...)` is looking for a column `sub$par1`, but there isn't one. Try using `aggregate(as.formula(paste("B~",par1,"+A")), data=sub, FUN="sum")`

Comment: @Hugh -> The goal of this function was to output a geom for ggplot. So i would give it a df with all the source data and parameters that i would like to aggregate by. The first step was to filter the data then i would aggregate. The parameters are to be different columns. So that when the function was a bit more dynamic. I did not want to make multiple function where the only difference was the column names.